# Lazy=true ignored for Hibernate + H2, but ok for Hiberante + MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, lazy-loading

H2 1.4.191.
Hibernate: 5.1.0.Final.
All Spring modules: 4.2.5.RELEASE.

How fix this?
Next code gives me result with children:

```
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "from Category where categoryParentId = :parentId").setLong("parentId", parentId).list();
//------------------------------------------------
<class name="com.domain.Category" table="Category">
    <id name="id" type="long" access="property">
        <column name="categoryId" length="20"/>
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="categoryName" type="string"/>
    <property name="parentId" column="categoryParentId" type="long"/>
    <bag name="children" table="Category" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="categoryParentId" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.domain.models.Category"/>
    </bag>
</class>
//----------------------------...
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

Comment: Which version of MySql are you using?

Comment: @TalAvissar, 5.7.11.